# In C++, is it possible to reference data-structure portions like stl list in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, reference, stl, unions

```
list<int> a;
list<int> &b = a;
```

Where each element added in `a` will be added in `b`, and any element deleted in `a` will also be deleted in `b`.

I would like to know, is it possible to refer to just portions of structures?

Something like this:

```
GeneralList : [___A,___B,___C]

________A :[_______&B,__&C]

________B :[__&A,_______&C]

________C :[______________]
```

GeneralList = The list that contains all elements (A,B,C,D)

A = It is a list that just refers to `GeneralList[B],GeneralList[C]`.

B = It is a list that just refers to `GeneralList[A],GeneralList[C]`.

C = An empty list.

the code would be

```
list<char> GeneralList;
GeneralList.push_back('A');
GeneralList.push_back('B');
GeneralList.push_back('C');
list<char> &A = {GeneralList['B'],GeneralList['C']};
list<char> &B = {GeneralList['A'],GeneralList['C']};
```

but I have syntax error

The objective is to be able to eliminate an element from the `GeneralList` and, because it is referenced in the other lists, the time to eliminate will be only 1 step.

I tried to use structures, like `union`, `reference_wrapper` but I can not understand them.
The reasons for using this pattern is that it should be ensured that when one element changes the other list are automatically updated.

The goal is to be able to call just one delete. So I dont need to delete in the other lists, and the complexity will be greater. GeneralList is a list of dependencies of a company, and A, B, C are modules of the same, when deleting an element of GeneralList I am saying that this module is already installed and as already installed I do not need to install it in other parts.

Comment: A 10 line test program would answer this and stick in your memory a lot more than just getting a "yes/no" from random internet people.

Comment: I'm just a fourth-semester student sorry. I tried everything I could

Comment: show what you tried

Comment: in your example a and b are the same list. so operations on a are in fact operations on b

Comment: References are aliases (and are usually implemented as pointers), so `b` is just an alias for `a`. There is only 1 `list` in memory, which both `a` and `b` refer to.

Comment: your second question about portions is entirely different. You need to be much clearer about what you are trying to do

Comment: Maybe I do not explain it well, I'll edit it right now.

Comment: You can certainly create separate lists that refer to elements of another list, using pointers or iterators.  But if you alter the main list, you risk corrupting the other lists, as they are still referring to elements that may not be valid anymore. So you would have to update those lists accordingly. You don't really gain anything.

Comment: that is the point. The goal is to be able to call just one delete. So you dont need to delete in the other lists, and the complexity will be greater. GeneralList is a list of dependencies of a company, and A, B, C are modules of the same, when deleting an element of GeneralList I am saying that this module is already installed and as already installed I do not need to install it in other parts.

Comment: @DanielOropezaSoria *Where each element added in a will be added in b, and any element deleted in a will also be deleted in b.* -- Maybe you're looking for the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)?  Please note at the article one of the reasons for using this pattern:  *It should be ensured that when one object changes state an open-ended number of dependent objects are updated automatically.*

Comment: I know that this problem would be solved with marks but the challenge is to be able to solve it in a time line without marks or verify, that's why I do say  references because when modifying this list it will modify in all others automatically because they occupy the same memory space

Comment: Ah, so you need some kind of view on the main list then.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I do not know if it's clear now

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Boost Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/range/doc/range.html)

Comment: @pm100 I do not know if it's clear now

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I do not know if it's clear now

Comment: you confused people with your first question, because the answer is yes and you show how to do it. But your actual question is quite different. For that one the answer is 'no', some languages have 'slices' (go for example) that allow something like that, but not c++

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a *view*, which could be defined as an entity with a container-like interface, that actually looks at (and in some cases, can modify) content of another container.

Up to C++14 there are no views in the standard library. The standard containers all contain their own objects. In C++17 there will be `string_view` and `array_view`, however they only support viewing a contiguous subset of the target container.  You will still need to roll your own implementation of the view that you describe in your question.